# How to get the bounding rect of selected text inside an <input>?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can use `document.createRange()` to get a range of individual characters in a textnode, then `Range.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the position on the screen of those characters. I want to do the same thing for text in an `input` element, which used to be possible in IE only with `createTextRange`.

This jsfiddle sums up the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/sobu5ug2/2/

I can't use the same method for an `input` because `Range.setStart/End` only works on the element level, not the character level, for an `input`. I also tried `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()` but that returns a bounding rect of all 0's. I'd like to do this without actually selecting the text, if possible.

Is there any way to do this in a modern browser? Thanks.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't need this, as you could just get the position of the input instead ?

Comment: If I understand it well, Try to copy the contents of the input (value) to an element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to do it:

https://jh3y.medium.com/how-to-where-s-the-caret-getting-the-xy-position-of-the-caret-a24ba372990a

You need to create a div, copy all styles of the input element into that div, copy text up to the selection into that div, add a span inside that div with the selection and then you can measure this span relative to the div before removing the div again.